# Usar tupla com parenteses em query no django

Tags: python, django, cursor

Fiz um cursor para obter os parent menus da minha aplicação, em seguida quero iterar cada parent menu e obter os menus associados a ele.
Porém, ao passar o parent com parâmetro, o segundo curso não funciona.

```
from django.db import connection
    parents=[]
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select parent from myapp_django_menu group by parent")
        parents=cursor.fetchall()
        print(parents)
        for p in parents:
            cursor.execute("select menu from myapp_django_menu where parent=%s group by menu",[p])
            menu=cursor.fetchone()
            print(menu)
```

o parametro p, é um item de um tupla no formato `[('p1',), ('p2',)]` desta maneira, entendo que o problema deve ser as aspas, parenteses e virgulas.
Como fazer esse p ser aceito como parâmetro?

Answer (score 2):

Já descobri meu erro, é uma tupla de tuplas, então no for eu estou pegando a primeira tupla e preciso passar um indice da tupla proveniente da tupla do for, fica algo assim:

...

```
 cursor.execute("select menu from myapp_django_menu where parent=%s group by menu",[p[0]])
```

...